# getComputedStyle failed to execute

Tags: javascript, getcomputedstyle

I have this simple bit of code:

```
var recipes = document.getElementsByClassName("recipes");
var recipesStyle = window.getComputedStyle(recipes, null);
```

It returns this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use `var recipesStyle = window.getComputedStyle(recipes[0], null);`

Comment: document.getElementById('yourElementId') worked for me instead of using document.getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong: `recipes` isn't an element (it's a *collection of elements*).

If you want the styles associated with the *first* recipe element, either add `[0]`:

```
var recipes = document.getElementsByClassName("recipes");
var recipesStyle = window.getComputedStyle(recipes[0], null);
// Here ------------------------------------------^
```

...use `querySelector`, which will just return the first element matching a given CSS selector:

```
var recipe = document.querySelector(".recipes");
var recipesStyle = window.getComputedStyle(recipe, null);
```

Or if you wanted to deal with the styles of *each* recipe element, you might use a loop:

```
var recipes = document.getElementsByClassName("recipes");
for (var n = 0; n < recipies.length; ++n) {
    var thisRecipesStyle = window.getComputedStyle(recipes[n], null);
    // ...
}
```